# Getting error accessing state in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to route the user to specific route according to user's role. I am using redux as state management tool. I am trying to access the user object from `auth` state to route the user.

When I login to the system below are the logical steps that take user to route.

1. Login to the system
2. Authenticate and load the user
3. Redirect user to route according to role

I am trying to access the `user.role` in `DashBoard` component which is causing the error.

Please help me understand the bug.

**1. Action to login to system**

```
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config ={
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify({email, password});

    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/api/v1/midasUsers/login',body,config);

        dispatch({
            type:LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload:res.data
        });

        dispatch(loadUser());

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        const errors = err.response.data.errors;
        if(errors){
            errors.forEach(error =>dispatch(setAlert(error.msg,'danger')));
        }

        dispatch({
            type:LOGIN_FAIL
        })
    }

}
```

**2.loaduser to localstorage to authenticate:**

```
export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {

    console.log("I am inside loaduser");

    if(localStorage.token){
        setAuthToken(localStorage.token)
    }

    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/v1/midasUsers/auth');
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED,
            payload:res.data
        })
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: AUTH_ERROR
        })
    }
}
```

**3. DashBord.js - Component to route the user**

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
//import store from '../../store';
//import {loadUser} from '../../action/auth';

const Dashboard = ({auth:{user,loading,isAuthenticated}}) => {        
    if(user.role === 'admin'){
        return <Redirect to='/adminLandingPage'/>
    }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
    auth:PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth : state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{})(Dashboard);
```

I am calling `loadUser` everytime `App.js` is mounted the same function after `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action calls this route

`GET /%3Canonymous%3E`

Please help me understand the issue

```
auth.reducer
import {REGISTER_SUCCESS, 
        REGISTER_FAIL, 
        USER_LOADED,
        AUTH_ERROR,
        LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        LOGIN_FAIL,
        LOGOUT} from '../action/types';


const initialState = {
    token : localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated : null,
    loading: true,
    user:null
}

export default function(state= initialState, action){
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch (type) {
        case USER_LOADED:
            return{
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated:true,
                loading: false,
                user:payload
            }
        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:    
            localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token);
            return{
                ...state,
                ...payload,
                isAuthenticated:true,
                loading:false,
            }
        case REGISTER_FAIL:
        case AUTH_ERROR:
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
        case LOGOUT:            
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return{
                ...state,
                token:null,
                isAuthenticated:false,
                loading:false
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

```
store.js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

```
index.js in reducers folder
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import alert from './alert';
import auth from './auth';

export default combineReducers ({
alert,
auth
});
```

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { login } from '../../action/auth';


const Login = ({ login, isAuthenticated, user }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = e =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login(email, password);
  };

  //Redirect if logged in
  if(isAuthenticated){
      //console.log(user.role);            
      return <Redirect to ="/dashboard"/>
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className='large text-primary'>Sign In</h1>
      <p className='lead'>
        <i className='fas fa-user' /> Sign Into Your Account
      </p>
      <form className='form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='email'
            placeholder='Email Address'
            name='email'
            value={email}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='password'
            placeholder='Password'
            name='password'
            value={password}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
            minLength='6'
          />
        </div>
        <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary' value='Login' />
      </form>
      <p className='my-1'>
        Don't have an account? <Link to='/register'>Sign Up</Link>
      </p>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Login.propTypes = {
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated:PropTypes.bool
};

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
    isAuthenticated : state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    user:state.auth.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
  { login }
)(Login);
```

I have this login component which redirects user to dashbaord and at dashbaord i am not able to access the user.role from state

Comment: How are these reducers set in your store?

Comment: @alex067: I have added auth.reducer to question. Please have a look

Comment: I mean can you show how your reducer is actually declared in your store

Comment: @SagarMahadik: can you add the snippet for your combine reducer?

Comment: @alex067: Have added store.js in the question

Comment: @Vaibhav Singh : Have added combine reducer to the question

Comment: What is the bug you are receiving?

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of null

Comment: You have an issue fetching the response from your post. Can you console.log (res) to see if theres any errors with your post?

Comment: try {
  const res = await axios.post('/api/v1/midasUsers/login',body,config);
   
   dispatch({
           type:LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload:res.data
      });

Comment: data:
status: "Success"
token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVkZWZhNGMwNDQ2MDliMWMzNDc3MzVlYSIsInJvbGUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTU3Nj..I am getting token back as response

Comment: @alex067  I have added login component to the question which redirect user to the dashboard where I am checking for the user.role which is undefined

Comment: const res = await axios.get('/api/v1/midasUsers/auth');
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED,
            payload:res.data
        })

can you console.log res here? it looks like the issue is coming from here

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry but application never hits the get request, the console.log never gets called. The error I get on console is Dashboard.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of null
    at Dashboard (Dashboard.js:11). Line where I am trying to access the user role.

Comment: If I hit localhoast:3000 , everything works fine. const res = await axios.get('/api/v1/midasUsers/auth'); this returns email: "s@gmail.com"
mobile: 12345678
name: "Sagar"
role: "admin"
__v: 0
_id: "5defa4c044609b1c347735ea"

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for your time. After putting console.log it was evident that I was calling dashboard component before updating user in state and hence the error. I updated the routing logic to check for user as well and now the functionality works as expected.